# Can I return authentication errors to my EJS page by putting them in HTTP response variables, then refresh my modal with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

My login route is activated by login form submission (in express)

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    if (!user) { return console.log("E-mail or password is incorrect..."); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Is there a way I can write code to 'listen' for the HTTP response of the 'login' route, and when it responds, the code can access variables set in the response, so they can then be input into the page (and refresh that part of the page)?

I know with AJAX I can refresh part of the page by requesting data from the backend, but I don't know how to run the '/login' route to get the error and simultaneously run an AJAX call to get that error and refresh the page...

Comment: I think I realised you don't make the HTTP request using the form, as well as making an AJAX request, you only make an AJAX request and send the input data through that. I will try it.

Comment: I believe u meant Request object right? because ur login method is just responding with redirect if u want all user entered data u can access it from request object and store those in variable for ur use.

Comment: @ShivamSood No I meant response. I don't need data sent from the page, I need to send data back to the page (an error message if user login info doesn't match database), so that I can display it in a modal.

Comment: so u want ur page to redirect if no user is found? ( to error page)

Comment: @ShivamSood That's exactly what I don't want, which is the difficulty. I want to remain on the same page, without refreshing, and display errors if any are generated on the server side. I think I have almost done this with AJAX, calling an AJAX request, which sends the form data, and the XMLHttpRequest object will contain the errors if the AJAX request is successful (and if there are errors, otherwise it will redirect to home page).